# Node Red Unique Identifier

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, mac-address, node-red

What I want to achieve:

I want to have an **unique identifier** for each raspberry pi which is running node-red and simultaneously being a mosquitto client so that the clients can publish their unique identity to the broker.

My idea:

I want to use the MAC-Adress of the raspberry Pis' as an unique identifier but how can I get the adress in a node-red **function block**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it running doing this:

In the `node-red` folder I added this to the global context:

```
functionGlobalContext: {
  osModule:require('os')
}
```

In one of the function blocks of node-red I added this piece of code:

```
const os = global.get('osModule');
result = os.networkInterfaces();
```

I'm saving that in the payload and then I'm publishing an initial mqtt post to the broker.